# Can ffprobe accept something other than a file path to retrieve video metadata?

Tags: javascript, filereader, ffprobe, angular-file-upload

I am trying to grab video metadata off a user's upload. I am using angular-file-upload and FileReader to upload the file. I would like to use ffprobe to grab the metadata, but it seems to only accept file paths, which I don't have access to. Is there a way ffprobe can take a file object or buffer?

Comment: ffprobe cannot run in the browser (unless someone converted it to JavaScript) and your upload could be saved out as file on server and run as a path argument to ffprobe, no?

Comment: Yes there is a javascript ffprobe, but I ended up finding a different solution for extracting the metadata. Thanks anyway!

Comment: So why not share your solution here so the question can be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I ended up using clipchamp to extract the metadata. We were already planning on using the clipchamp api to compress our media, and we found out that it returned all the metadata we needed as well so there was no need to search for outside resources.